# Dividing a matrix to the power of r

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, factorial

How come in the following equation:
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{rt^{r-1}A^r}{r!}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{(tA)^{r-1}A}{(r-1)!}$$
when you divide by $r$ from the LHS, the power of r on matrix A goes away in the series on the RHS. I understand when you divide by r the factorial goes from $r!$ to $(r-1)!$ What property allows you to divide by $r$ from $A^r$ to get $A$?

Thanks, I'm trying to be a physics major but my math background isn't the best. This website has been helping!

Comment: Please accept my answer, will you?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize there was a place to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the power of $r$ does not go away. It has been disguised: $t^{r-1}A^r=t^{r-1}A^{r-1}A=(tA)^{r-1}A$, the last equality holding because scalars are freely swappable in a matrix product.

Comment: Wow, I feel a little silly for not being able to do that myself. Thank you so much! It is hard not having taken advanced math in high school and the professor seems to skip over "trivial" steps :(. I really want to understand what happens at each step. This really helps!